# Mentioning Payment Terms in Proforma Invoice PDF Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress with Woocommerce plugin.

I am making a B2B Website wherein Proforma Invoice is needed and in that Proforma Invoice PDF template, I want to specify payment terms in such a way that if sub total of order is less than or equal to INR 50,000 or $1000, then the customer has to make full payment. Else make 40% advance payment.
Only two currencies are being used.

The following code gives this output as such for any value of subtotal:
*Payment Terms : 40% advance & balance 60% prior to despatch*

```
<p>Payment Terms :
<?php 
global $woocommerce;
$tolamt = (int)$woocommerce->cart->total;
if (get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() == '₹' ) {
    if ($tolamt<=50000 ) { 
        echo " 100% Advance" ;
    }
} elseif (get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() == '$') {
    if($tolamt<=1000 ) {
        echo " 100% Advance" ;
    }
} else { 
    echo " 40% advance & balance 60% prior to despatch";
}
?>
<br>
</p>
```

Where am I going Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code. I'm assuming the invoice is calculated on order, so first you need to access the order with `wc_get_order`

```
<p>Payment Terms :
<?php 
global $woocommerce;
$tolamt = (int)$woocommerce->cart->total;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
$order_currency = $order->get_currency();
$order_currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $order_currency );

if ($order_currency_symbol == '₹' ) {
    if ($tolamt<=50000 ) { 
        echo " 100% Advance" ;
    }
} elseif ($order_currency_symbol() == '$') {
    if($tolamt<=1000 ) {
        echo " 100% Advance" ;
    }
} else { 
    echo " 40% advance & balance 60% prior to despatch";
}
?>
<br>
</p>
```